# Do Google chrome and Firefox developer edition browsers share session?

Tags: google-chrome, session, firefox, browser, firefox-developer-edition

I have been logged-in into stackoverflow in Chrome browser with my Google credentials and then I open stackoverflow in Firefox Developer Edition browser and tried to login again in Firefox with Google credentials. I have been automatically logged-in. I clicked to  log out and after logout when try to login with Google credentials, I have been automatically logged-in again.
As per my knowledge, Firefox and Google chrome doesn't share the session.

- So, I am curious to know whether this new FDE browser share session
  with chrome or is it the feature of StackExchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Firefox/Chrome doesn't share sessions. Auto relogin is feature of Stackexchange. You can completely uninstall one of the browsers, clear cache and retry and this will still work.

Firefox/Chrome uses entirely different browser engines. Firefox based on Gecko and Chrome is based on Blink - each with it's own data storage formats. They may use `sqlite`, but Chrome still saves secure passwords with operating system security features like `keystore` in osx. Firefox saves password internally.  Even if they wanted to, for data exchange both browser would need to arrive at a common data exchange formats with a LOT of security implications.